# Raspberry Pi 2: routing table has no the specified gateway

Tags: linux, ssh, connection, raspbian

I have this routing table:

[image: Routing Table]

I used SSH to be able to use my Raspberry Pi on my laptop screen. Everything was fine until I opened my browser and wanted to ping Google in the terminal. I can't, though.

When I try to ping `8.8.8.8` (Google's nameserver), I get the message below the routing table in the image above. But the strange thing is, when I run SSH with PuTTY on a different laptop, the Internet connection is fine. So probably the problem is on my laptop.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Ok I got the problem is why. The problem is because of NETWORK KILLER MANAGER. I hate itç How can i fix it please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using `192.168.1.1` as a gateway, yet you have configured `192.168.137.0/24` as the network.

You should either try to configure the default gateway to - perhaps - `192.168.137.1` or your IP address to `192.168.1.x`.

An `ifconfig` output would be handy.

Edit:

Add default gateway:

```
route add default gw 192.168.137.1
```

You might also need to remove current default gateway(s).

Comment: yes yes on my firends's leptop the gateway is 192.168.137.1 but in my leptop is like that - 0.0.0.0 as show in image above. Probably that's way. I will try it whenever i can and if i can i am gonna inform you sir. Thanks a lot.